# Phalcon 3 RuntimeException: Trying to call method get on a non-object

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to code a library with Phalcon 3 and I get an error when calling the Cookies service.

Can anyone help me please?

**The error i get is:**

> RuntimeException: Trying to call method get on a non-object

My code is next:

**loader.php**

```
$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir,
        $config->application->incubatorDir.'Mailer/',
        $config->application->libraryDir.'gAuth/',
    ]
)->register();
```

**Services.php**

```
$di->setShared('cookies', function () {
    $cookies = new Cookies();
    $cookies->useEncryption(false);
    return $cookies;
});

$di->set('gauth', function(){
    $gauth = new gAuth();
    return $gauth;
});
```

**authController.php**

```
public function authAction(){
    $this->gauth->store();
}
```

**gAuth.php**

```
use Phalcon\Crypt;
use Phalcon\Http\Response\Cookies;


class gAuth
{
    public    $token;
    protected $cookie;
    private   $secret;
    private   $crypt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->secret = '************;
        $this->crypt = new Crypt();
        $this->cookie = new Cookies();
        $this->cookie->useEncryption(false);
    }

    public function storeToken()
   {
    // here I get the error: Trying to call method get on a non-object
    $this->cookie->set('tkn', '***', time() + 3600, '/', null, 'web.com', null)->send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$this->cookie` in your controller, but in your DI you used `cookies`.

So you need to use `$this->cookies`.

Also you don't need to recreate the cookie object in your controller. What's the point of using the DI then?

Comment: Hi Timothy. Thanks for your answer. I don't know how I can access a service inside a library. gAuth.php is located in the library directory and loaded from loader.php file but I don't know why when I try to call a service there it cannot be loaded. The error i get is: Error: Call to a member function set() on null

Comment: You can extend your class of the `Component` or you can call the DI something like `Di::getDefault()->get('cookies')`